# Orbeon - how to validate file content uploaded by user

Tags: file, validation, orbeon

I need to validate content of pdf file sent by "File Attachement" component, using Webservice, uploaded by user.

How to do that ?

Action Value Change is not called

ver.orbeon-4.4.0.201311042036-PE
Thanks
Piotr

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

That probably requires a few steps:

1. Determine when the upload is complete. With recent versions of Orbeon Forms, the event[`xxforms-upload-done`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/XForms%3a-Events#xxforms-upload-done) can be used.
2. Send the content of the uploaded file to a service. The file can be a binary file, but there is a way to [submit binary content](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-advanced-submissions#TOC-Submitting-binary-content).
3. Depending on what the service returns, mark the control valid or invalid. You could do this with an attribute on the element holding the uploaded file's URL, e.g.: `<my-upload valid="true"/>` and then use a constraint like `constraint="@valid = 'true'"`.